# Mouse Pointer Script

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am currently trying to identify the script behind the mouse pointer script in the heading of the following wordpress template:
http://prism.umbrella.al/agency/

However, I cannot identify how this was done. Is this done with the paralax script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code used to run the nifty canvas effect is located near the bottom of the source, in a script tag :

```
    (function() {

    var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;

    // Main
    initHeader();
    initAnimation();
    addListeners();

    function initHeader() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        target = {x: width/2, y: height/2};

        largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

        canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // create points
        points = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < width; x = x + width/20) {
            for(var y = 0; y < height; y = y + height/20) {
                var px = x + Math.random()*width/20;
                var py = y + Math.random()*height/20;
                var p = {x: px, originX: px, y: py, originY: py };
                points.push(p);
            }
        }

        // for each point find the 5 closest points
        for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var closest = [];
            var p1 = points[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                var p2 = points[j]
                if(!(p1 == p2)) {
                    var placed = false;
                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(closest[k] == undefined) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(getDistance(p1, p2) < getDistance(p1, closest[k])) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            p1.closest = closest;
        }

        // assign a circle to each point
        for(var i in points) {
            var c = new Circle(points[i], 2+Math.random()*2, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)');
            points[i].circle = c;
        }
    }

    // Event handling
    function addListeners() {
        if(!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
        var posx = posy = 0;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        target.x = posx;
        target.y = posy;
    }

    function scrollCheck() {
        if(document.body.scrollTop > height) animateHeader = false;
        else animateHeader = true;
    }

    function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }

    // animation
    function initAnimation() {
        animate();
        for(var i in points) {
            shiftPoint(points[i]);
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        if(animateHeader) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            for(var i in points) {
                // detect points in range
                if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 4000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.3;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.6;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 20000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.1;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.3;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 40000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.02;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.1;
                } else {
                    points[i].active = 0;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0;
                }

                drawLines(points[i]);
                points[i].circle.draw();
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function shiftPoint(p) {
        TweenLite.to(p, 1+1*Math.random(), {x:p.originX-50+Math.random()*100,
            y: p.originY-50+Math.random()*100, ease:Circ.easeInOut,
            onComplete: function() {
                shiftPoint(p);
            }});
    }

    // Canvas manipulation
    function drawLines(p) {
        if(!p.active) return;
        for(var i in p.closest) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            ctx.lineTo(p.closest[i].x, p.closest[i].y);
                            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(35,221,207,'+ p.active+')';
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function Circle(pos,rad,color) {
        var _this = this;

        // constructor
        (function() {
            _this.pos = pos || null;
            _this.radius = rad || null;
            _this.color = color || null;
        })();

        this.draw = function() {
            if(!_this.active) return;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(35,221,207,'+ _this.active+')';
            ctx.fill();
        };
    }

    // Util
    function getDistance(p1, p2) {
        return Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2);
    }

})();
```

Took a little hunting.

I will say - please don't just yank this code and run with it. Someone lovingly crafted this sweet little script, and it would be rude to steal it, outright. You should use it as a learning tool, and grow your own knowledge in the process.

Happy coding!